# Error 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' on installation of signalr 5 nuget package

Tags: signalr, blazor-server-side

I have a application that worked perfectly until the moment where i installed signalR. I'm receiving the following error:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Encodings.Web, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.
```

I'm working on blazor server-side And i receive the error there:

```
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();  <------error
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/Chathub");
```

Comment: add [System.Text.Encodings.Web package in version 5.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Encodings.Web/5.0.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use VisualStudio IDE, Enter `Install-Package System.Text.Encodings.Web -Version 5.0.0` at Package Manage Console.

I have same issue while studying blazor tutorial, "Use ASP.NET Core SignalR with a hosted Blazor WebAssembly app". I can't find essential reason, it didn't occur error.